# Why can limits of integration (angle values for Theta) be coterminal in double integrals in polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, upper-lower-bounds, multiple-integral

In James Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (8th Edition), this is how he presents the formula for changing from rectangular to polar coordinates in a double integral:

> If $f$ is continuous on a polar rectangle $R$ given by $0 \le a \le r \le b$, $\alpha \le \theta \le \beta$, where $0 \le \beta - \alpha \le 2\pi$, then
> $$\iint_R f(x,y)dA = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\int_a^b f(rcos\theta, rsin\theta)rdrd\theta$$

I'm not sure why it's okay to let $(\beta - \alpha) \in [0,2\pi]$ instead of letting $(\beta - \alpha) \in [0,2\pi)$ or $(\beta - \alpha) \in (0,2\pi]$. In other words, **why are coterminal limits of integration not a problem?**

Wouldn't $(\beta - \alpha) \in [0,2\pi]$ mean that you're adding the value of $f$ over that same boundary point twice? When I asked my professor, he said that doesn't matter for integration, but I still don't understand why.

For example, if you were to integrate $f(x,y)=1$ over the circular region defined by $r=1$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, wouldn't you be adding an extra 1 to the final sum, because you're including both $\theta=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$? But when I evaluate the actual integral, I get the proper area that matches the area from evaluating $\pi r^2 = 1$. Could someone help explain what I'm missing?

Comment: To understand this intuitively, think about the geometric interpretation of the integral of a nonnegative function $f$ in one variable: the area between the graph of $f$ and the $x$ axis, obtained by approximation with areas of rectangles. What is the area of a segment? Is $0$. Hence, integrating on $[a,b]$ or on $[a,b)$ leads to the same result, because in the point $b$ you are adding up the area of a segment. In higher dimensions, you have that the volume of a surface area is $0$, and so on.

Comment: When you say segment, you're referring to the segment from (b,0) to (b, f(b))? So because that is a segment (or rectangle with zero width), the area is 0?

Comment: CPLTarun: Exactly.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now. Just like a segment from $(b,0)$ to $(b,f(b))$ has an area under $f$ of $0$, the volume of the line segment at $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = 2\pi$ is $0$. We're talking about intervals in the domain space; the integral over a single "value" in the domain results in $0$, thereby not changing the final integral value.